# Need help in data normalization ideas to create Excel Pivot chart

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, pivot, database-normalization

I have a Excel sheet in the form:

[image]

I want to convert it into:

```
DtWeek  WsName  CValues  TValues
```

so that I can have a pivot Chart where I can just select a WS name and then see its graph of the CValue and TValues, omiting all other WsNames.

What be a good approach to avoid manually copy pasting it! I think of dumping it into a sql dbs and then do a

```
select WsName, 
       ,case when Current/Target='CurrentEcap' then.....
```

but thats all I can think off. lost after that!
For a moment, transposing the data seems to make it look neater, but then soon thats no help either. Mostly because I don't know how to plot the Current Values as discrete items and not a sum or count on the vertical axis. (with ww/dtweek on the horizontal).
Would there be any other easier approach?

Comment: You're on the right track, the data does need to be re-shaped.  Usually this is easier to do at the source.  Do you have the ability to talk to the person/system that send you this report, and request the 4-column table you've described?

Comment: Its generated by some software in a worse form. I excep screen I have included is after I have cleaned it a lot more.

Comment: Then I would go ahead and write a macro to convert it to the form you want. Not very difficult. Start in cell C2, copy cells C1, A2, C2, C3 into a row on a blank worksheet, move right one cell, repeat, keep going till the end of the row, start over 2 rows down.

Comment: is there any way to plot a column's values in pivot chart without any kind of summation?

Comment: You didn't have VBA as one of your tag. Are you open to that idea? It is better to just keep it inside Excel and not involve SQL Server.

Comment: I don't have any VBA knowledge. But am open to learn it if it will simplify things. I do have to use excel in the end to generate the Pivot table so I may just drag and drop different items and see graph change real time during meetings, rather than having to generate all possible graphs beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend one of two methods depending on how many DtWeek columns you have to process. You don't necessarily need to de-normalize Current/Target into two different fields to get the results you want as you can pivot this field by Column to get a data series for your chart that is split by Current vs. Target. You would need to do this in a normal Excel Chart but it is optional with a Pivot Chart. However, you definitely need to nornmalize DtWeek so that you can pivot on this field by Row in your Pivot Table.

**A Few DtWeek Columns - Append**

If only a few, I'd recommend loading the current table into an RDBMS like Access or SQL and running multiple append statements to create a new table. Then, set a WHERE clause for each DtWeek value so that only those values will be appended, and create new field named DtWeek with a value that you specify (in Access, DtWeek:'201310', for example). Also, if the data is non-volatile and/or you get one week of data at a time, you may only need to run this once.

**Many DtWeek Columns or recurring reports - UNPIVOT**

In this case I would look at SQL Server UNPIVOT by DtWeek. Then you can either link from Excel or run an additional query that uses CASE to create Target versus Current columns. The MSDN blurb [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) or [this](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/DustinRyan/ssis/1193/t-sql-unpivot-y-goodness) article (which has a nice before-and-after data visual) may be helpful. This is a better option if you get new data every week and/or the data is volatile.

If your source data is a real mess (such as from a legacy application that dumps formatted text in an non-relational format), you might also want to consider a product like Monarch, where you build custom "traps" and the software models the data for you.

Best of luck!